# HTML not centering

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="flag_container">

    <div class="flag_1">
        <img class="flag_img_1" src="../images/gb.png"></img>

        <div class="speaker_1">
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div class="flag_2">
        <img class="flag_img_2" src="../images/at.png"></img>

        <div class="speaker_2">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="flag_3">
        <img class="flag_img_3" src="../images/de.png"></img>

        <div class="speaker_3">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="flag_4">
        <img class="flag_img_4" src="../images/nl.png"></img>

        <div class="speaker_4">
        </div>  
    </div>

</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.flag_img_1{
    width:160px;
    height:80px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag_img_1:hover+.speaker_1{
    display:block;
}

.speaker_1{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;   
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-top:-90px;
}

.flag_img_2{
    width:160px;
    height:80px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag_img_2:hover+.speaker_2{
    display:block;
}

.speaker_2{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green; 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-top:-90px;
}

.flag_img_3{
    width:160px;
    height:80px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag_img_3:hover+.speaker_3{
    display:block;
}

.speaker_3{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;  
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-top:-90px;
}

.flag_img_4{
    width:160px;
    height:80px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag_img_4:hover+.speaker_4{
    display:block;
}

.speaker_4{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:orange;    
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:170px;
    margin-top:-90px;
}

.flag_container{
    padding:80px 0;
}
.flag_1{
    padding-left:406px;
}

.flag_2{
    float:left;
    padding-left:163px;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.flag_3{
    float:right;
    padding-right:163px;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.flag_4{
    padding-top:160px;
    padding-left:406px;
}
```

Which creates the following display:

[image]

and on hover:

[image]

Where the blue square is a placeholder for an image.

This all works fine.

I want to make the display responsive, so when the screen gets smaller, the flags take a central formation like:

[image]

My problem is, it will not stay central, but will keep a fixed position in relation to the left. Here is my CSS:

```
.flag_container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
}

.flag_1{
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.flag_2{
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;

}

.flag_3{
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.flag_4{
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.agendaHeading{
    float:left;
    font-size:120%;
}

.flag_img_1:hover+.speaker_1{
    display:none;
}

.flag_img_2:hover+.speaker_2{
    display:none;
}

.flag_img_3:hover+.speaker_3{
    display:none;
}

.flag_img_4:hover+.speaker_4{
    display:none;
}
```

I have tried every combination I can think of, and read many posts but it does not work. I suspect it is something to do with the structure of my divs preventing it from working as I want?

An example of CSS where I have managed to centre a div in the way I am trying to here is:

```
.box1{
    width:85%;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    float:none;
    height:50px;
}
```

But this does not work.

Apologies for the long post/amount of code, but to demonstrate my problem I have to include it all.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?? or have you ever come to know about bootstrap where you can really no need to take care of responsive thing??

Comment: use `media-query` or bootstrap for make responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using pixels and no % in your paddings.

Did you tried to use % instead of fixed pixels in your padding-left,top and right on you css of .flag_*? I've bee playing a little bit with your code and using % gives you a more efficient way of organize the divs on a resized screen.

Comment: unfortunately changing to % does not help